# Databinding in C# - property names as strings

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, user-controls

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115328/how-can-i-do-databinding-in-c) I am quite sure how a property of a class can be bound to a TextBox in my UserControl. Still I am quite uncomfortable with accessing properties through strings. Any connection to the type or even existence of that property (on both sides) is lost.
My main problems with this attitude are that:

- IntelliSense stops working -> easy to make a mistake, less convenient;
- whatever is written there will not be checked until it is called -> the mistakes are likely to stay unnoticed until the worst possible moment...

Is there some other way to create a UserControl representing one class that is connected to an instance of that class and remains synchronized with it? (besides doing it manually with events)

Answer (score 0):

> (besides doing it manually with events)

It must be clarified that one and two way data binding **does** depend on events. Please read about [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

That said, you can databind without hard coding strings representing property names in your code.

One way to do it is through custom attributes. You can decorate certain properties in your data model you want your user control to bind to. This way when the `DataSource` is set in your user control, via reflection you can search the `DataSource` object for custom `Attribute` decorated properties and bind to them:

```
public class MyDataModelObject
{
    public int NotBindableProperty { get; }

    [MyBindableAttribute]
    public string BindableStringProperty
    {
        get {...}
        set {...}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you are forced to use strings, that is just the basic `NotifyPropertyChanged` event mechanism.  For example, the [Prism Framework](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/03/12/PrismWPFGuidanceReferenceImplementationMicrosoftPatternsPractices.aspx) provides a simple wrapper that takes the a Linq `Expression> as an argument and uses reflection to get the property name (beware though; I have in one instance seen this cause a performance problem when used on a property that was updated many times in a short time period).

You could easily write a wrapper like this yourself without the need for using the entire Prism framework like so:

```
class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( ProeprtyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        PropertyChanged( this, e );
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression )
    {
        // you'll want to add some error checking here
        var name = ((MemberExpression)propertyExpression).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged( new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );
    }
}
```

Now you can use it by simply passing in the property:

```
class Whatever : NotificationObject
{
    private string _foo = String.Empty;
    public string Foo
    {
        get { return _foo ?? String.Empty; }
        set
        {
            if( !_foo.Equals( value ) )
            {
                _foo = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged( this.Foo );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you ever refactor the property `Foo` you don't have to worry about updating a string as well.  This doesn't solve the problem on the other side though.  A DependencyProperty would, but you have the string issue internally, which IMP is preferable because it is only a duplication in one place (in the class) as opposed to *n* number of duplications externally.  It's not perfect, but it helps.