# How to expose DataBind in winform control c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to bind `Mybutton.Enabeld` to a bool lacated at another class 
but when I write `Mybutton.DataBinding` I get error that

> "MyButton does not contain definition for DataBinding "

How do I expose it? 
I know it is possible and used it once before like that

```
    var ScriptListBoxSelectedIndexBinding = new Binding("SelectedIndex", Control_ScriptHandler.ControlScriptIteratorHanlderAgent, "ScriptCounter", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    ScriptListBox.DataBindings.Add(ScriptListBoxSelectedIndexBinding);
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate post here - [How can I do Databinding in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115328/how-can-i-do-databinding-in-c)

Comment: @Vinvinvinvin No ! my problem is not I cant bind ! . 
My problem that I cant even right MyCTrl.DataBind !!